# Keras: confusion matrix with predict_generator

Tags: keras, tensorflow

I'm not using `ImageDataGenerator` because i'm using hdf5 files. I used DataGenerator class (1) to feed data to the `model.fit_generator`. How can I get the confusion matrix given that I have batches of random data? I know how to get it with `model.predict` using sklearn.

(1) https://stanford.edu/~shervine/blog/keras-how-to-generate-data-on-the-fly#

Answer (score 0):

```
loaded_model.predict_generator(generator=test_generator)
```

will give us a set of probabilities

```
y_true = test_generator.classes
```

will give us true labels

Because this is a binary classification problem, you have to find predicted labels. To do that you can use:

```
y_pred = probabilities > 0.5
```

Then we have true labels and predicted labels on the test dataset. So, the confusion matrix is given by:

```
font = {
'family': 'Times New Roman',
'size': 12
}
matplotlib.rc('font', **font)
mat = confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred)
plot_confusion_matrix(conf_mat=mat, figsize=(8, 8), show_normed=False)
```